# Null datatable Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a function to create a datatable in Shiny based on department numbers and how many times an event happened in that department during a time period.  My issue is that if the date range is short enough, no departments will have had the event occur.  In those instances, I get the error `Error in rowSums(x) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions` which initially just appeared within the Shiny app and you could just ignore it.  Now, the app crashes and you have to go back to R to look at it.

I understand why the error is occurring but I don't know if there's a way around it for my situation because I don't know if the events occur until the data is subset.  The function is called a number of times in my code, so I don't want to write an `if` statement outside the function each time it is used.

I tried adding `if(length(b$Department <= 1)){tab<-renderDataTable({datatable(NULL)})}` right after defining `b` and then had an else statement around the remainder of the function, but I get the message `Warning: Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected`

I have also tried other `if` statements such as creating a dataframe full of `NA`s but this returned the original error message.

```
dept.table<-function(df, date1, date2){
  a<-df[which(DATE >= as.Date(date1) & DATE <= as.Date(date2)),]
  b<-as.data.frame(table((a[,c("Event", "Department")])))
  d<-reshape(b, direction="wide", idvar="Event", timevar="Department")
  names(d)<-sub('^Freq\\.', '', names(d)) 
  d$Total<-round(rowSums(d[,-1]), 0)
  levels(d$Event)<-c(levels(d$Event), "Total")
  d<-rbind(d, c("Total", colSums(d[,-1])))tab<-DT::renderDataTable({
  datatable(d, extensions="FixedColumns", options=list(dom='t', scrollX=T, fixedColumns=list(leftColumns=1, rightColumns=1)), rownames=FALSE)
 })
}
```

Sample data

```
 df<-data.frame(Department=rep(100:109, 3), Event=rep(c("A", "B", "C"),10),
     Date=sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2018/09/01'), by="day"), 30))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, but I figured out a solution. There were two different issues.  One when there was no data and another when there was only 2 departments, so I needed two if statements.

```
dept.table<-function(df, date1, date2)  {a<-df[DATE >= as.Date(date1) & DATE <= as.Date(date2)),]
   b<-as.data.frame(table((a[,c("Event", "Department")])))
   if(nrow(b)==0){tab<-DT::renderDataTable(NULL)}
   else{d<-reshape(b, direction="wide", idvar="CODE", timevar="Department")
        names(d)<-sub('^Freq\\.', '', names(d)) 
        if(ncol(d)>3){d$Total<-round(rowSums(d[,-1]), 0)
          levels(d$Event)<-c(levels(d$Event), "Total")
          d<-rbind(d, c("Total", colSums(d[,-1])))
          tab<-DT::renderDataTable({
               datatable(d, extensions="FixedColumns", options=list(dom='t', scrollX=T, fixedColumns=list(leftColumns=1, rightColumns=1)), rownames=FALSE)})}
        else{tab<-DT::renderDataTable(datatable(d))}
   }
 tab
}
```